# how far can nfc on mobile phone read rfid tags

Tags: range, nfc, rfid

I google on the internet and find that nfc on mobile phone is said to be able to read rfid tag (HF tag). Does anybody test how far it can read RFID tag, or what's reading range for RFID tag? Is it possbile to read RFID tags within 1 meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My informal test just now, with the Nexus S, resulted in a read distance of about 2 cm, maybe a little more, but not much. A larger read distance would probably drain the battery quite fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Another question is that,  is the power consumption of nfc reader high? why do u say it can drain the battery quite fast? I have just read the wiki and found that the power consumption is below 15ma.

Comment: I assume so. When the phone is looking for tags it doesn't keep the field on for vary long. Instead it pulses. I assume they did that because of battery life. But NFC was designed with a maximum distance of 10 cm (maybe 20 cm, I can't remember exactly) so it has a very low detection range. Even my dedicated reader only had a 5 cm range on the card I tested. But the more range you want, the more power you have to put out.